# cannot return promised value to paypal button

Tags: javascript, php, json, paypal

I am trying to implement paypal express checkout on my website (Ubuntu 14.02 LAMP) with Codeigniter v2 and bespoke php. I have chosen the server implementation model where I am responsible for returning the payment id to paypal (to create the payment). However, even though I am happy that I can return a json structure of the form {"payToken":"token_value"} from my php functions, the paypal checkout.js keeps on saying my first character is a '<', and the window just dies. I can only assume somehow I am returning HTML but simply cannot find the problem. Am I missing some important detail about how I code the return value to the function when the button js script code in my html is as follows:

```
 return paypal.request.post('/payment/create/').then(function(res) {
                            return res.payToken;
                        });
```

This is copied from paypals guides and my create function returns the json as above.

Any help would be really apperciated as I have spent weeks going nowhere.

Thanks, Paul

Comment: Could it be that your php is not interpreted? `<` sounds like `<?php`... take a look at the network tab in the developer tools of your browser to see the response.

Comment: Can you check your chrome network tab and see what the response is?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions - I have looked at the network tab of chrome tools and then clicked on the create function and the response tab says "no data". However, I am tracing my scripts using php error_log to a file and I can see the script returning the json structure. So where is it going! All these tools are wonderful in an experts hands but I finding it totally bewildering alas. Fundfamentally I dont see how my return value is connected to the promise .then clause of the javascript, and even worse I cannot see what exactly it is doing either. Thoughts?